# Keyboard controls show up while using 360 controller

Tags: fable-3

I recently started playing Fable III on my PC and everything was going fine for the first couple hours. After restarting my computer and launching the game again I started seeing the keyboard/mouse HUD show up while not creating input from my controller.

This makes menus a pain to navigate, and the HUD constantly changing on me is giving me a headache. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and have you found a fix for it?

Controller is a wired 360 controller for Windows.

Comment: When the game first started, did you click with your mouse/keyboard or controller? Like wise during the game did you accidently moved your mouse during menu or such?

Comment: @Lyrion - Nope. They both sit on a completely undisturbed surface.